# What do you call the person in a group who everyone agrees with? Opposite of iconoclast, maybe?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the person in a group whose opinion everyone agrees with?

Here's the background: we have a group of people whose job is to render opinions. At the end of the session we see which person disagreed with others most often ("the iconoclast"), and the person who agreed with others most often ("the *what*?")

We do not consider it worse to be in agreement with more people. That's why we don't like opposites of iconoclast like "conformist" or "yes-man."

"Trendsetter" is nice, but since opinions are offered separately and secretly, it's not true that other people *follow* this person's opinion -- they just happen to agree.

Comment: Lowest common denominator (just joking).

Comment: I don't think there's a word for it. They're just "ordinary" or "undistinguished" and we don't usually need to refer to them specifically.

Comment: hello and welcome. please note the requirement at the tag for single-word requests: *. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.*

Comment: A monopole: A central position, a medium, a neutrum, the hard core, the centre of gravity, majority, establishment, the common ground, ground truth, the rock in the sea (that's idiomatic, right? viz G *Fels in der Brandung*), top of the pops, common sense dictator

Answer (score 4):

We settled on "bellwether." It kind of connotes "where you look to see which way the wind is blowing." It sort of hides the "follower" aspect, even though the literal meaning of bellwether has to do with sheep and does connote leader/follower

:-\

I'll leave the question unanswered in case something better comes along.

Comment: +1 for "bellwether". In Britain, in the context of [general elections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_the_United_Kingdom#General_elections), a constituency which happens to elect a member of the same party as gets the largest number of MPs is termed a bellwether. There is no "following" here, because voters don't know which party will get the largest number of MPs until after they've voted.

Comment: @RosieF Yes, a "bellwether seat" is one which trends with the party in government over a very long period of time. The "most bellwether" seat in the UK, at the present time, is Dartford, where the result has reflected the overall result in every general election since 1964.

Answer (score 1):

Since the word is to have nothing to do with following at all (that excludes words like *leader* and *trendsetter*), but could be used after the fact (which also excludes the word *bellwether* from another answer, since it is normally used predictively), I would use the more neutral [**representative**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/representative#h2):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : one that represents another or others
>   **2** : a typical example of a group, class, or quality : SPECIMEN

From the question:

> At the end of the session we see which person disagreed with others most often ("the iconoclast"), and the person who agreed with others most often ("the what?")

This could be turned into a sentence such as the following:

> Her views were the most *representative* of our own.
>   She was a good *representative* of our group.

Or, with a variation of the word:

> He best *represented* our views.

---

A related word is [**exemplar**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exemplar):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : one that serves as a model or example

Answer (score 0):

An "iconodule" is the opposite of an "iconoclast" in the core meaning of the latter. "Bellwether" and "contrarian" seem like a natural pair.

Narrowly, the agreeable person is the mode of the array of agreements...

Answer (score 0):

Your question strikes me as confusing if these parts are supposed to be in agreement, because the first part implies uniqueness, solitude, or *singularity* - call it what you want - but the latter part implies multitude:

`What do you call the person in a group whose opinion everyone agrees with?`

`... since opinions are offered separately and secretly, it's not true that other people follow this person's opinion -- they just happen to agree.`

It's not obvious in which way timeliness is supposed to make a difference, or how you would know that who's first, if it's secret--unless you were either the omni-potent narrator, representing personal pseudo omni-potent mind state, or faking omni potence to effect the reader.

I might be mistaken and the latter part just describes "trendsetter". In that case, I beg to differ with the description.

---

If we can tell mind-state from action (cue behavioralism) then I'd recommend

> first mover

as in *first mover advantage*; this is however not unique to agreeable positions, but often risky speculation.

---

If you aim to describe a point of a homogenous mass to describe it's inertia, impuls or momentum, I suggest

> center of gravity

as a rather colorful metaphor. Also cp "apex", "turning point", "anchor".

---

For a meronymic abstraction I'd suggest

> common sense

---

vice versa, for a meronymic *pars pro toto*--I guess that's what you are really looking for--try *center of gravity* on for size, again, equivalently try

> model [citizen, voter, politician, student]

This fits e.g. the model student, who is like others of the same stereotype, and certainly influenced by prior examples, but by definition able to form an individual opinion. Ironically, they are often voted *represantative* (node to @JasonBassford). This is difficult of course, because the definition is circular, but at least it's not a contradiction. Similarly cf *primus*.

In the sense *leader*, but without *winning* over others, nor *winning-over* others, try *ray of hope*, *fountain head*, *spear head*, *proginator*, *predator*. For someone who's in contest with the others, *alpha [male]* obviously fits (incidentally not the center of gravity of a flock; that would be the females; the metaphor is lacking). I'm affraid I know no term that would be completely devoid of value judgement. If *alpha* followed its proginator, Semitic *alef* (seemingly "bull"), then it could have been semantically close to "bellwether".

---

Since your own answer, *bellwether*--which surely is often confused with the unchangeable *weather* and thus only loosely associated with the animalic metaphor--contradicts your second constraint, I will likewise suggest one:

> propagator

not *propagandist* but "one who propagates [information, signals]". A propagator is in principle not the *initiator*, so it fits the bill.

---

### After all, It would be really helpful if you added an example sentence.